# Position sticky works incorrect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using `position: sticky` to stick header that stays little lower than document starts(near 42px below). As I set up sticky position and `top:0` property as I would like to use jQuery `on(scroll)` event to get the position of my sticky element and has changing for `$.addClass(someClass)` with transition.

But in console.log attached to Chrome PC browser inspector it shows always current fixed position as `top:0` even if header stands at 42px off the window-top.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="top-head">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="contact">
            <div class="contact-field">
                <a href="mailto:info@reen.com">
                    <img src="img/icon-mail.png" alt="">
                    <p>info@reen.com</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-field">
                <a href="tel:+00 (123) 456 78 90">
                    <img src="img/icon-phone.png" alt="">
                    <p>+00 (123) 456 78 90 </p> 
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-network">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><img src="./img/icon-facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="./img/icon-google.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="./img/icon-twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="./img/icon-pinterest.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="./img/icon-behance.png" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="./img/icon-dribbble.png" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-box">    
            <a href="" class="logo">
                <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <nav>
                <div><a href="">Home</a></div>
                <div><a href="">Portfolio</a></div>
                <div><a href="">Blog</a></div>
                <div><a href="">Pages</a></div>
                <div><a href="">Features</a></div>
                <div><a href="">Mega Menu</a></div>
                <div><a href="">Contact</a></div>
            </nav>
            <div class="search">
                <button type="image" name="submitSearchIco" class="deco-button"> 
                    <img src="./img/icon-find.png" alt="Search" class="deco-button">
                </button>
                <button type="submit" name="submitSearch" class="subm-button" for="searchFor"> 
                    <img src="./img/icon-find.png" alt="Search" class="subm-button">
                </button>
                <input type="text" name="searchFor" id="search-inp" class>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</header>
```

SCSS

```
 header{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: white;
    padding: 2.5% 0;
    transition: padding .5s;
    }
.transform-header{
    padding: 1.5% 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log($('header').scrollTop());
    if($('header').scrollTop() === 0){
        $('header').addClass('transform-header');
    }
});
```

Comment: URL: http://reen.fattrack.tk/
URL Categories: Phishing, Internet Services
Reputation: High Risk

Comment: @PaulAbbott its not fishing site... Its demo template site. Free domain .tk attached to hostinger.com.ua hosting system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like below example  with your html and css code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var s = $(".sticker");
 var pos = s.position();        
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windowpos >= pos.top ) {
   s.addClass("stick");
  } else {
   s.removeClass("stick"); 
  }
 });
});
```

```css
div.wrapper {
 margin: 260px auto;
 width:600px;
 background:#efe;
  height: 3900px;
}
div.sticker {
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 background: #ece;
 width: 190px;
}
.stick {
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
}
.marker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
  right: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sticker">fixed pos </div>
</div>
```